# How to ignore pathtoolong exception?

Tags: c#

I've got some simple code as such...

```
try
{
    files = root.GetFiles("*.*"); 
    //throws exception filetoolong exception.  Skip file and move
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
     throw;
}
```

The issue is this may throw an exception if the file path is too long...

> System.IO.PathTooLongException was unhandled
>   Message=The specified
>   path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name
>   must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less
>   than 248 characters.
> Source=mscorlib

Is there any way just to skip files that are long, currently my program just stops, how do I avoid this exception for now?

Comment: Do you know what the `catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)` block is there for, and what it does in your case? I suspect you should read up on [try-catch-statements and exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) first.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown by `root.GetFiles("*.*")`?

Comment: If you don't care that you cannot get to these files then just add a catch for System.IO.PathTooLongException.

Comment: @HansPassant - That is correct I dont care about it, so will my code continue if I catch this exception and simply `catch{}`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Of course I need that exception, I have read about exception handling.  That exception catches anyone who does not have rights to specific files.

Comment: @HansPassant - Okay that looks to be good, I can catch an empty exception {}.  Thanks!

Comment: @oJM86o: And throws it again, so the block isn't really very useful without any additional content.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It's currently just a place holder, I have to log all these exceptions.

Comment: @oJM86o: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. Sometimes, people here just paste some code that they have found somewhere without knowing what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can avoid the exception is not to try to enumerate a folder with files which exceed the specs given which are based on the MAX_PATH constant or work with no files.

I've not used it but you could try AplhaFS - http://alphafs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

More information about the limitations on file path length:
[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx)

There *are* a few ways you can work around this, but in order to use those workaround methods, you'd have to likely P/Invoke to the very specialized subset of calls that support filepath lengths > MAX_PATH